# rtree spatial indexing isn't working with pandas

Tags: python, spatial, spatial-query, spatial-index, r-tree

I'm trying to use spatial indexing to speed up intersection of spatial objects, to check whether points are in a polygon, if not then discard them from the dataframe. Initially it was implemented in a laborious way without indexing, such as

```
 for id,row in inst.iterrows():
     if not pr.contains(Point(row['lng'].astype(float),row['lat'].astype(float))):
         inst.drop(id,inplace=True)

 for id,row in ht.iterrows():
     if not pr.contains(Point(row['lng'].astype(float),row['lat'].astype(float))):
         ht.drop(id,inplace=True)
```

This is very slow. Now I'm trying to make a rtree equivalent

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from shapely.geometry import shape, Point
import shapefile
from rtree import index

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # import data from csv, shp
    inst = pd.read_csv('inst.csv',encoding='utf-8')[['lat', 'lng']]
    ht = pd.read_csv('ht.csv',encoding='utf-8')[['lat', 'lng']]

    myshp = open("./shp/pr.shp","rb")
    mydbf = open("./shp/pr.dbf","rb")

    pr = shape(shapefile.Reader(shp=myshp, dbf=mydbf).shapes()[1])

    print(pr.bounds)

    inst_idx = index.Index()
    ht_idx = index.Index()

    # indexing
    for idx,row in inst.iterrows():
        inst_idx.insert(idx,(row['lng'].astype(float),row['lat'].astype(float),row['lng'].astype(float),row['lat'].astype(float)))

    for idx,row in ht.iterrows():
        ht_idx.insert(idx,(row['lng'].astype(float),row['lat'].astype(float),row['lng'].astype(float),row['lat'].astype(float)))

    # intersection and give some possibly false positive result
    inst_nb = list(inst_idx.intersection(pr.bounds))
    ht_nb = list(ht_idx.intersection(pr.bounds))

    # see if they are really in the polygon
    for id in inst_nb:
        if not pr.contains(Point(inst.iloc[id]['lng'].astype(float),inst.iloc[id]['lat'].astype(float))):
            inst.drop(id,inplace=True)

    for id in ht_nb:
        if not pr.contains(Point(ht.iloc[id]['lng'].astype(float),ht.iloc[id]['lat'].astype(float))):
            ht.drop(id,inplace=True)
```

I expect this to produce the same result as the first block of code. However, it keep throws index out of bound error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Chu/Documents/dssg2018/inst_per_ht1.py", line 40, in <module>
    if not pr.contains(Point(inst.iloc[id]['lng'].astype(float),inst.iloc[id]['lat'].astype(float))):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1373, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_axis(maybe_callable, axis=axis)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1830, in _getitem_axis
    self._is_valid_integer(key, axis)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1713, in _is_valid_integer
    raise IndexError("single positional indexer is out-of-bounds")
IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds
```

Please feel free to any sample data within column name `lat` and `lon`

Comment: You may want to create a GeoDataFrame and do this in GeoPandas. There's a nice blog that covers using a rtree spatial index with a GeoDataFrame here: https://geoffboeing.com/2016/10/r-tree-spatial-index-python/